How can I tell if a recruiter is actually representing a candidate they present?
It seems like some of these recruiters that contact us are not actually working with the candidates they present.  For instance, a couple times, we have indicated an interest to interview and their response is that the candidate is busy or not responding to them or some other excuse.
Did they just scraped their info from Linked In or something and then try to "claim" them?  What is happening and how can I prevent this?

I fail to see the scam here. How are these recruiters who don't actually have any candidates making any money?

In the context you used.  Who exactly is "we"?

@PhilipKendall Same way email scammers make money. Once in a hundred times they will actually manage to match a candidate and claim their cut.

Assuming you got a resume with at least a name you should be able to find the candidate yourself.

Note the candidate may simply have accepted a job elsewhere and no longer has any reason to talk to you or the recruiter. It happens. Move on to the next candidate, revisit this one if they reappear.

On the job-hunting side, it is common knowledge that recruiters will offer / advertise jobs where they don't have an agreement with the employer already. It is highly likely that they will do the same to employers.
It is impossible to prevent such behavior. But you have the right to put those recruiters on a "do not use" list and ignore any emails / resumes / phone calls from them.

Is there some reason to believe the recruiters aren't telling you the truth?
If a candidate is on the job market, they're probably sending their resume out to a lot of different places.  When they get a job offer, they probably stop responding to recruiters.  Unless you happen to be responding exceptionally quickly to candidates and offering well above market compensation and benefits, there is a decent chance that someone else has hired the candidate you're interested in by the time you're ready to request an interview.  The worse the recruiter, the more likely they're relying on resumes sent in weeks or months ago rather than maintaining active conversations with their candidates and the more likely they're sending in people that are no longer on the market.
Sure, if a recruiter has submitted a dozen candidates and every one of them is unavailable when you want to interview, start ignoring the recruiter because they're wasting your time.  It's not a scam, they're just not particularly good at their job.  They're sending out a bunch of resumes hoping to get lucky rather than spending the time qualifying their candidates for each job.
